# pylint doesn't detect most code violations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-3.7, pylintrc

I'm using a Python3 virtual environment on Windows.

Here is the command I run from my virtual environment.

```
(myproject) C:\Users\jp\myproject> pylint src
```

When I run pylint, it only uses a subset of its checkers (`missing-docstring`, `broad-except`...). For example, it does not use `attribute-defined-outside-init`.

How to get Pylint to use all (or most) of its checkers?

Comment: Do you have a `.pylintc` file in the `myproject` or anywhere else that might be restricting what is being run?

Comment: I was using a pylintrc file, but I deleted it.